# Devise/LDAP sessions looking for a password even though User model doesnt require one.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, ldap

I am using Devise and the devise_ldap_authenticatable gem to authenticate users. Users sign in with their company username and password which authenticates them and creates a session.

When I first started on the project I was kind of new to user auth and just followed the devise tutorial, which meant that our User model had a username, email, and encrypted password. We've since realized that because the authentication is being done by ldap, our user model doesn't need a password attribute.

Which works fine when the users login credentials are correct.

Back when the User model still had the encrypted_password attribute, an invalid login would redirect back to the sign_in and flash 'Invalid email/password' but now it gives me the error:

```
"ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Devise::SessionsController#create Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password"
```

I set the `config.ldap_create_user` to false in initializers/devise.rb but it looks like its trying to use the password to create the session.

Comment: add password as attr_accessible .